# How to set auto refresh for grocery crud?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I am using grocery crud library to show my database record and it is working perfectly. But how can I get real time record from `database` without refreshing the page. To do this I put a script in template file name is `list_template.php` in flexigrid theme.

```
setInterval(function(){ $('#crud_search').trigger('click'); },10000);
```

which is refreshing the record too but it is always showing me record from starting not the current page. The current page means if i am on page 3 it is showing page 1 as interval.

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you solve this. Can you share the balance of your JS code that performs the AJAX request?

Comment: add tag and update text

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with autoload and i solved doing this:

I just created a js file called refresh on assets/js/refresh, and added the following:

**js file**

```
var interval = null;

window.onload = function() {
    interval = setInterval(callFunc, 5000);    
};

function callFunc() {
       $("#ajax_refresh_and_loading").trigger("click");
}
```

**Controller side**

```
$jsfile = 'assets/bootstrap/js/refresh.js';
        $crud->set_js($jsfile);
```

I hope this is what you need.